# Html Image control not displaying image

Tags: c#, html, image, src

Below is my html image control:

```
<img alt="" src="C:\Users\hkalidindi\Desktop\Feedback.jpg" style="height: 19px; width: 20px"/>
```

[image: my aspx design page showing image]

But after debugging it is not showing me any image:

[image: After debugging image is not visible]

I am new to dotnet..please help me to solve this issue...I know how to display image in image control but i am bit confused about the html image control...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use image only from the content of your website. So copy the image in your website folder say Images and access your image as `<img alt="" src="..\images\Feedback.jpg" style="height: 19px; width: 20px"/>`. Or you could use Asp.NET Image control and set image path in Server code using

```
myImage.ImageUrl=Server.MapPath("Images\Feedback.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Users\hkalidindi\Desktop\"

Is only local, try uploading it to a website such as http://imageshack.us, http://tinypic.com, grab the direct link and put that in the source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="URL">
```

Here URL = The url of the image.

Possible values (for src):

**An absolute URL** - points to another web site (like src="http://www.example.com/image.gif")

**A relative URL** - points to a file within a web site (like src="image.gif")

Refer: [HTML  src Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the image in your local folder. Add the image to the 'Images' folder in your solution and link to that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is being referenced from a folder that is in your websites application/dir. Then you can reference it simply by using a tag like so:

```
<asp:Image id="imgFeedback" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/_common/img/feedback.jpg" />
```

Or set the image path on the server side:

```
this.imgFeedback.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("\_common\img\feedback.jpg\");
```